# PHP curl returning blank strings

Tags: php, curl

I started off using `file_get_contents()` and it returned string(9259) in which every character is a space (aka. its a lot of empty).  After some research I tried using `curl()` and after a few struggles with getting the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` to work it brought me right back to where I was, string(9259) of all blank.

I am attempting to retrieve the tracking information on multiple packages automatically and the code for a single iteration is as follows:

```
function curl($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17' );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false  );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        $data = curl_exec( $ch );
        var_dump( curl_getinfo( $ch ) );
        echo curl_errno( $ch ) . '<br/>';
        echo curl_error( $ch ) . '<br/>';
        curl_close( $ch );
        return $data;
    }
```

$url for one instance is https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=055575670028673&cntry_code=us

My question is essentially why am I receiving the string(9259) of blank characters?  I expected to receive an actual string representation of the website.

Comment: Do they not expose an API to get this information as opposed to having to do a screen scrape?

Comment: I tried your code with that URL, I got the web page contents.

Comment: @Barmarr how did you run it? I seem to recall having this issue before using Xampp despite enabling my curl

Comment: I ran it in PHP Tester, a Mac application that runs PHP locally.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Fedex doesn't like it when you scrape pages, has detected that you are doing so, and is returning dummy data?

They do have APIs for this: http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/index.html